# Search specific movie in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, omdbapi

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import MoviesItem from './MoviesItem'
  
  const Movies = ({search}) => {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])

    const fetchUserData = async() => {
        if(search){
      const mov=await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=35b97ba4&s=${search}`)
      const res=await mov.json()
      console.log(res)
      setMovie(res.Search) 
        }
        else
        {
            const mov=await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=35b97ba4&s="jawan"`)
            const res=await mov.json()
            console.log(res)
            setMovie(res.Search)
            
        }
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchUserData()
      // eslint-disable-next-line   
    },[])
    return (
        <div className='container'>
        { <div className="row">
               {movie.map((m)=>{
                    return <div className='col md-4'>
                            <MoviesItem title={m.Title} poster={m.Poster}/>
                        </div>
                })}
        </div> }
        
      </div>
     
    )
            }
  export default Movies
```

When I type my movie name in search box and click search button it should show me my searched movies but it doesn't. When I reload my server from terminal then it shows the results I want it to fetch my result when I click search button. I tried calling the API infinite times in `useEffect` but that is not the optimal solution even though it satisfies my needs because of daily limits which is 1000 calls.

Home.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Search from './Search'
import Movies from './Movies'

const Home = () => {
    const [searchContent, setSearchContent] = useState('');
    const handleSearch = (searchTerm) => {
       
        setSearchContent(searchTerm);
        console.log(searchTerm)
      };
    
  return (
    <div className='container'>
     <Search onSearch={handleSearch}/> 
     <Movies search={searchContent}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Would you post the `Search` component source code?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken an educated guess at the content of the components you didn't share yet.
But I don't think the issue is related to those so I figured I'd answer.

The issue you're having is because the `fetchUserData` function is being called but the useEffect isn't getting the redefined value of `fetchUserData`. You can tackle this by simply moving the function *into* the `useEffect` and adding the value of `search` in the effect's dependency array.

Then:

1. when the user presses, the "search" button
2. `handleSearch` will be called in the `Home` component
3. that set's the value of `searchContent` in the `Home` component`
4. the change in value for `searchContent` triggers the `useEffect` to run again and updates the UI with a list of results based on the search term

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const {useState, useEffect} = React;
  
  const Search = ({onSearch}) => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="button" onClick={() => onSearch(search)}>Search</button>
      </div>
    )
   };
  
  const Movies = ({search}) => {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        if(search){
      const mov = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=35b97ba4&s=${search}`)
      const res=await mov.json()
      console.log(res)
      setMovie(res.Search) 
        }
        else
        {
            const mov=await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=35b97ba4&s="jawan"`)
            const res=await mov.json()
            console.log(res)
            setMovie(res.Search)
            
        }
    }
  
        fetchUserData()
      // eslint-disable-next-line   
    },[search])
    return (
        <div className='container'>
        { <div className="row">
               {movie.map((m)=>{
                    return <div className='col md-4'>
                            <MoviesItem title={m.Title} poster={m.Poster}/>
                        </div>
                })}
        </div> }
        
      </div>
     
    )
            }
            
  const MoviesItem = ({title, poster}) => <div>{title}</div>

const Home = () => {
    const [searchContent, setSearchContent] = useState('');
    const handleSearch = (searchTerm) => {
       
        setSearchContent(searchTerm);
        console.log(searchTerm)
      };
    
  return (
    <div className='container'>
     <Search onSearch={handleSearch}/> 
     <Movies search={searchContent}/>
    </div>
  )
}


    ReactDOM.createRoot(
        document.getElementById("root")
    ).render(
    <Home />
    );
    </script>
```

Note:
Make sure you're listening to the React warnings in the console:
`Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` which is a case of adding the `key` prop when mapping over elements (`.map`)

Also noteworthy for other readers, I had to follow guidance from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit) as a React snippet doesn't work properly when defining `async` functions (hence why the code is in a `script` tag, and also why the code is poorly formatted/indented)

Comment: Great to hear! If you found this answer helpful, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer and upvote too